# Postgis St_Project calculation method

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, gps, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry

I`m trying to implement postgis **St_Project** analog on C++ (calculation method is taken from here - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
#include <cmath>

struct GeoPoint
{
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
};

static const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137.0;
static double degToRad(double deg) { return (deg * M_PI) / 180.0; }
static double radToDeg(double rad) { return (rad * 180.0) / M_PI; }
static GeoPoint projectGeoPoint(const GeoPoint& gpt, double distance, double bearing)
    {
        double angular = distance / EARTH_RADIUS;
        double bearingRad = degToRad(bearing);
        double latRad = degToRad(gpt.latitude);
        double lonRad = degToRad(gpt.longitude);

        double lat = std::asin(std::sin(latRad) * std::cos(angular) +
                                       std::cos(latRad) * std::sin(angular) * std::cos(bearingRad));

        double lon = lonRad + std::atan2(sin(bearingRad) * std::sin(angular) * std::cos(latRad),
                                                          std::cos(angular) - std::sin(latRad) * std::sin(lat));

        return  { radToDeg(lon), radToDeg(lat) };
    }

int main()
{
    GeoPoint gp = {0, 0};
    GeoPoint gp_new = MapsMath::projectGeoPoint(gp, 100000, 45);
    std::cout.precision(14);
    std::cout << "longitude_new - " << gp_new.longitude << " latitude_new - " << gp_new.latitude << std::endl;
}
```

Result is: **longitude_new - 0.63523085373227 latitude_new - 0.6351918164606**

I expect that postgis **St_Project** function will give exatcly same result:

```
select st_astext(st_project(st_makepoint(0,0,4326), 100000, radians(45)))
```

However, this query issues different result: **longitude_new - 0.635231029125537 latitude_new - 0.639472334729198**

What I`m doing wrong and how achieve exactly same result akin postgis St_Project?

Comment: ST_Project seems to take geography as input http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html so I believe that it knows that Earth is somewhat flat while your formula probably does not because it has only one constant http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html. The difference is in sixth decimal place and thus about ten centimeters which is not huge for 100 kilometer distance if you have some practical implementation in your mind.

Comment: It could also be the difference between a great circle and a geodesic.

Comment: The second paragraph on the linked page basically says it all.  The calculations do not take into account that the world is not a perfect sphere, but a wee bit flattened (an oblate ellipsoid).  The other [page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) from the same site may provide a better method

Comment: Digging a little deeper it appears that PostGIS uses this [library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS uses the C implementation of [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net), so I suggest using the native C++ implementation.

ST_Project uses a direct geodesic calculation, e.g. see [these docs](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1Geodesic.html).